# PHP time add HH:MM:SS

Tags: php, time

I am trying to add total worked hrs for the employees for the 7 days week period below code is not working for me, not sure what am i doing wrong as I am not a `PHP` expert, idea please?

```
<?php 
            $time1 = $row_Roster['sunday_start'];
            $time2 = $row_Roster['sunday_end'];
            list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time1);
            $startTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds);

            list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time2);
            $endTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds);

            $add = $endTimestamp - $startTimestamp;
            if($seconds < 0) {
            $seconds+=60*60*24; 
            }
            $seconds = $add % 60;
            $minutes = ($add / 60) % 60;
            $hours = floor($add / (60 * 60));



            $sunday = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

            echo $sunday;
            if ($sunday >8)
            echo ('</br><span class="smallred">Long Shift</span>');
?>
```

does it make sense

```
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time1);
    $Timestamp1 = mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time2);
    $Timestamp2 = mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time3);
    $Timestamp3 = mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time4);
    $Timestamp4 = mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds);

    $add = $Timestamp1 + $Timestamp2 + $Timestamp3 + $Timestamp4;
    if($seconds < 0) {
        $seconds+=60*60*24; 
    }
    $seconds = $add % 60;
    $minutes = ($add / 60) % 60;
    $hours = floor($add / (60 * 60));
    $total = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);             
    echo $total;
?>
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, it would be helpful to know where if you want assistance. Debugging technique: try echoing out each of the variables to identify what works and doesn't

Comment: Why do you need `if($seconds < 0) {` before $seconds is defined?

Comment: with current code the output is....  2797735:00:28

Answer (score 2):

You make this way to complicated.

First just put all your formatted days into an array (`$formattedWorkTimeWeekdays`).

Then go through each day with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and calculate the total amount of seconds per day and save it in `$secondsWorkTimeWeekdays`.

After this you can sum all seconds per day together with [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and you get the total amount of work for this week in seconds in the variable `$totalSecondsWorkTimeWeek`.

And at the end simply calculate the hours, minutes and seconds out of it.

```
<?php

    $formattedWorkTimeWeekdays = [
            $monday,
            $tuesday,
            $wednesday,
            $thursday,
            $friday,
            $saturday,
            $sunday,
        ];

    $secondsWorkTimeWeekdays = array_map(function($formattedWorkTimeDay){
        list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(":", $formattedWorkTimeDay);
        return ($hours * 3600) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds;
    }, $formattedWorkTimeWeekdays);

    $totalSecondsWorkTimeWeek = array_sum($secondsWorkTimeWeekdays);

    $hoursWorkTimeWeek = $totalSecondsWorkTimeWeek / 3600;
    $minutesWorkTimeWeek = ($totalSecondsWorkTimeWeek % 3600) / 60;
    $secondsWorkTimeWeek = ($totalSecondsWorkTimeWeek % 3600 % 60);

    echo $total = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hoursWorkTimeWeek, $minutesWorkTimeWeek, $secondsWorkTimeWeek);

?>
```

**EDIT:**

After your edit your have 2 completely different codes, which aren't related to each other at all. For your first revision I gave the answer above.

Now in your edited code you just seem to have 2 dates. You can just create two `DateTime` objects and get the difference from them, e.g.

```
$workTimeStart = new DateTime($row_Roster['sunday_start']);
$workTimeEnd = new DateTime($row_Roster['sunday_end']);

$workTimeDifference = $workTimeStart->diff($workTimeEnd);
echo $workTimeDifference->format("%h hours %i minutes %s seconds");
```

Comment: Hi Rizier getting error on the first line, $days = [$Monday

Comment: @DEDE Then your php version is probably under < 5.4 (`echo phpversion();`) Just change `[...]` with `array(...)`

Comment: @DEDE Then just use this code: http://pastebin.com/7cuKCkc1 (Just extracted the anonymous function into a normal function)

Comment: array(...) is still the same problem

Comment: thank you.. its much better, it does add the total hours but only does it for one row from database ..

Comment: *one row from database* huh? What do you mean with this? Please show us your **full** and **real** code

Comment: @DEDE So where are we now with this question?

Comment: i am using the same code..this code is in a repeat region, something stoping the  repeat..

Comment: @DEDE As I already said above: Show us your **full** and **real** code and what you are actually want to do.

Comment: I get the time diff like...$time1 = $row_Roster['sunday_start'];
    $time2 = $row_Roster['sunday_end'];

Comment: how can i send you the page, maybe you will understand better??

Comment: @DEDE As I already said, **edit** your question and **show your code!**

Comment: I edited the question and added the code, not sure why this part of your code is stoping the repeat region.. """"function calculateSecondsFromFormattedWorkTime($formattedWorkTimeDay)
  {
        
  list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $formattedWorkTimeDay);
        return ($hours*3600) + ($minutes*60) + $seconds;
        
  }""

Comment: @DEDE Your edited code is completely different to your original one. I updated my answer now, but your question is **unclear!**

Comment: Hi Rizier, I am identifying how many hours an employee worked each day with this code:  

            $time1 = $row_Roster['sunday_start'];
            $time2 = $row_Roster['sunday_end'];
            list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time1);
            $startTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds);
            .
            .
            .
            $sunday = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes,       $seconds);
                echo $sunday;

Now  i need to add mon to sun worked hours to find the total hrs, your answer breaking up the html repeat region...

Comment: Originally I was using this code to add all up, but it doesn't add the 0.30 minutes

<?php 
        $total = ($monday + $tuesday + $wednesday + $thursday + $friday + $saturday  + $sunday); 
 
      echo $total;
   ?>

Comment: @DEDE **edit** your question show your current code. Then show what the current output is and what you expected to get. ^^ From the comments above I have no idea what you want to do

Comment: @DEDE And now I still need to know what the current output of this code is and what you expected to get?

Comment: @DEDE What and where is the difference now?

Comment: difference is something in your code only giving one row of data (repeat region is not working, below is your code you sent..

Comment: Thanks Rizier for your patient.. will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculations and calling `sprintf`, you can use [gmdate function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php):

```
//the same code summing the weekdays seconds
$add = $Timestamp1 + $Timestamp2 + $Timestamp3 + $Timestamp4;
print gmdate("H:i:s", $add);
```

Comment: Hi User 4035.. result is something like this.. 00:11:252797735:00:28

Comment: @DEDE Ahh, sorry, I put the incorrect variable into the answer. Can you show me $add value? Maybe, it's too big for 2 digits for hours